# Modify LUA script to let Mouse press Alt if Leftclick follows after a Rightclick within a certain timespan

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

A friend is using a LUA script for this Logitech mouse in a game, which performs a "press left-alt" action if he clicks and holds the right mouse button and then also clicks the left mouse button:

```
function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock")then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat 
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    PressAndReleaseKey("lalt")
                    repeat
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
    end
end
```

I have different settings, I do not click and **hold** the right mouse button but just click it once and my leftclick may then follow immediately after or after 1-2 seconds.
So I would need the script to perform the "press left-alt" action only if I have clicked the right mouse button and then also clicked the left mouse button immediately or within 2 seconds.

Could you guys help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
local RMB_time = -math.huge

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then  -- RMB pressed
      RMB_time = GetRunningTime()
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then  -- LMB pressed
      if IsKeyLockOn"numlock" and GetRunningTime() - RMB_time < 2000 then
         Sleep(20)
         PressKey("lalt")
         Sleep(50)
         ReleaseKey("lalt")
      end
   end
end
```